# Figure position left

Tags: graphics, align, margins, width, includegraphics

This is the code that I use to create a figure:

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth]{img/Info.png}
    \caption{Info \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that the figure is too small (it's a table with a lot of information) and I would like to make it bigger and more readable, making it starting from the left margin of the page (now it starts align with paragraphs, closer to then center of the page).

Do I have to modify something in `\includegraphics` parameters?
[image]

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete small document. your image already should occupy `0.9\paperwidth`. how big than you like to have?

Comment: @Zarko I added a screenshot.  As you can see, the figure goes from a point in the left, to the margin right. I would like to start it from margin left.

Comment: ah, you have table as image ... if your table is so huge, you should consider to rotate table- or redesign it (break long column headers into more lines).. also better is to include table code directly in document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: mwe]

This show how you can center the image when is wider that the text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth]{example-image}}
    \caption{Info \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\includegraphics` has no positional logic it is just positioned like a letter and you can adjust it in the same way `\hspace*{-2cm}\includegraphics{...}` will move it 2cm to the left.

Comment: Easy and straight forward! On another note, how to manage the space between texts and figures? Tried number of solutions but nothing seems to address it properly yet. It makes sense that when a figure can't be fit to a left over page space, that figure goes into position itself into the next page. However it seems there has to be a way to manage it without having to deal with too much of such empty spaces in between. Do you have another charm for that?

Comment: don't ask questions as comments on unrelated questions. The space between top or bottom floats and the main text is `\textfloatsep`  so perhaps you want to set that, or make an example and post as a new question @bonCodigo