# How to center image that refuses to center

Tags: graphics

I can't figure out how to properly center this image on the page (even if it is inside an `enumerate` environment)

[image: original image]

```
\documentclass[11]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=7in]{test.png}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: how it looks inside LaTeX]
And here is how it looks inside the enumerate enviorment
[image]

Comment: Remove the whitespace on the left side of the picture.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Your picture, i.e. the graphics, seems to have some white space on its left side. You need to trim it. This can be done by either changing the picture or using the `trimclip` package.

Comment: `article` does not have an `11` option,

Comment: your images do not match the code posted, the second appears to be in `figure` so a list is not relevant. ou can use `example-image` as the image and edit to make a real example that shows your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second image seems a figure float (there are a caption) where is irrelevant the enumerate environment,  and moreover, the image seem to fit the unequal margins. Note that the caption have the same width that the image but the width of  a normal caption is independent of the with of the image). So I suspect that this image is completely unrelated with what your are really asking, but without see code it is impossible to say more.

However, in your MWE and first image the problem is clear: It seems that the image have not empty spaces that you must crop, but a width of 7 inches (roughly 506pt) that is just too much  to fit into the text area (exactly 345pt) with the default margins, and therefore, no image could be centered with your settings:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % "11pt" not only "11".
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=7in]{example-image}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Making the image smaller, said to 80% of the text width,  any well cropped image will be correctly centered:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-7]
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2][1-7]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

If you want center a image wider that the text area, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461014/11604).